# Django Slugfield with how to treat underscore and hyphen the same in uniqueness?

Tags: django

I have a slugfield:

```
name = models.CharField(
    unique=True, validators=[
        validate_slug,
    ],
    max_length=255
)
```

However, I also want to ensure uniqueness is checked where hyphens and underscores are treated the same.

For this test case:

```
name1 = 'surfer_190_chap`
name2 = `surfer-190_chap`

record = Record(name=name1)
if record.full_clean():
    record.save()

record2 = Record(name=name2)
with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
    if record2.full_clean():
    record2.save()
```

The second name should fail, however it does not.

What I tried (I'm still researching how to do this part):

```
def validate_unique_underscore_hyphen(value):
    if '_' in value or '-' in value:
      ...

name = models.CharField(
    unique=True, validators=[
        validate_slug,
        validate_unique_underscore_hyphen
    ],
    max_length=255
)
```

Comment: If you want both to be treated as same, *better* to convert the `-` to `_` or vice-versa, on existing data as well as new entries. Then it will be less *painful* to checking the unique constraint.

Comment: You should use the already defined [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) that Django provides which has validation already.

Answer (score 0):

The correct place for this validation is in the model's `clean()` or `clean_<field>()` method as per [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

in `models.py`:

```
class Record(models.Model):

    ...

    def clean(self):
        if self.name:
            value  = self.name
            if '_' in value or '-' in value:
                expression = value.replace('-', '_').replace('_', '[-_]')
                
                raw_expression = r'^{}$'.format(expression)

                try:
                    match = Record.objects.get(name__iregex=raw_expression)
                    raise ValidationError(
                        _('%(value)s matches existing Record %(match)s'),
                        params={
                            'value': value,
                            'match': match.name
                        },
                    )
                except Record.DoesNotExist:
                    pass
```

This creates a regular expression - converting all instances of hyphen or underscore to the `or` of the 2.
A query is made using that regex to the database and if found a validation is raised.